# Axios do not return in nodejs

Tags: node.js, function, return, axios

why this fuction do not return anything for me. I think I have problem with axios.get.then(). So can you help to make it return message in then(reponse => ...)
The main question here is how can i save what `function testConnection()` return into a variable `message` to use it many time.

```
var axios = require('axios');

function testConnection() {

  axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie`, {
  params: {
    api_key: '72f444fa3d547f8ab38bcc6d9b00ffd6',
    sort_by: 'popularity.desc',
    include_adult: false,
    include_video: false,
    with_genres: 28,
    with_original_language: 'en',
  },
  }).then(response => {
      if (response.length === 0) {
        return "NOT OK";
      }  
        return "OK";
  })
}

var message = testConnection();
console.log(message);
```

Here is result when I run my code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ROfY.png)

Comment: Best to just `return axios.get(...)` and then use `testConnection().then(function(result) { ... });`.  More explanation in [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).  As it stands now, your `testConnection()` function has NO return value at all.  The `return` statements you do have just return from the `.then()` handler not from your host function.

Comment: I think you shoule unblock my question because my question is how to save  the return into a `variable`

Comment: You can't. That is all explained in the dup. The `axios.get()` finishes AFTER the function returns. Can't return an async value from the function. Must use a callback or promise.  Study the dup.   All explained there.

Answer (score 0):

In writing JS or any other NodeJS code there is rule to wait response from outside resource(EG: database, API).

```
var axios = require('axios');

function testConnection(callback) {

  axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie`, {
  params: {
    api_key: '72f444fa3d547f8ab38bcc6d9b00ffd6',
    sort_by: 'popularity.desc',
    include_adult: false,
    include_video: false,
    with_genres: 28,
    with_original_language: 'en',
  },
  }).then(response => {
      callback(response);
  })
}

var message = testConnection(function(response){
   if (response.length === 0) {
        console.log("NOT OK");
      }  
        console.log("OK");
});
```

Comment: Better to just return the promise that `axios.get()` already makes than to introduce another callback.

Comment: I want to use variable `message` many time. How can you fix it. Your code just print out it and I can't use `message` in other place.